# How to hide header & footer in printing page (window.print()) function in safari browser?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to hide header and footer section in printing page . I have used below css code to hide the header and footer .

```
 @page    {
  size: auto;  
  margin: 0;  
 }
```

Its only working in chrome & Firefox. But not working in safari. How can I fix this ? Please help me to find solution.

Answer (score 3):

According to [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=%40page), `@page` is not supported by Safari. Actually, `size` property is not supported well in IE/Edge and Firefox, so it is better not to use it.

To hide header and footer in print page. Maybe you can use media query:

```
@media print {
  header,footer { 
    display: none; 
  }
}
```